# Menu staying fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little function that makes my `headerbar` class fixed after i click on the menu button.

It works but when i click on the button again the `headerbar` stays fixed.

Here is my javascript:

```
// menu animation
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.menuBtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (this.classList.contains('is-active') === true) ? this.classList.remove('is-active'): this.classList.add('is-active');
        $('nav').slideToggle();
    });

});



$('.menuBtn').click(function() {

    $('nav').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('.headerBarm').css('position', 'fixed');

});
```

This code makes the `headerbar` class fixed:

```
$('.menuBtn').click(function() {

    $('nav').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('.headerBarm').css('position', 'fixed');

});
```

So basically I want it to change back to normal when I click the button again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $('.menuBtn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('is-active').toggleClass('fixed-position');
        $('.headerBarm').toggleClass('fixed-position');
        $('nav').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.fixed-position {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Not really.. `.headerBarm` does not get the `is-active`-class set.

Comment: @kevinseda No problem :)